# trouble using this script to make the button close by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to use the following script to make the button close its menu by clicking outside of it.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$('#trigger').click( function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

    $('#drop').toggle();

});

$(document).click( function(){

    $('#drop').hide();

});});
```

You can see the demo ([Ideal Fiddle])(http://jsfiddle.net/craigmdennis/H2Chj/2/)

But my button ([Problematic Fiddle]) (http://jsfiddle.net/xJ9ug/) isn't working that well. It takes a few clicks to open the menu. Would you please tell me what's wrong with the css or the script? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EaCXL/1/) fiddle. All you need is a simple condition check to make this work.

```
if ($('#dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

actually your code is correct .. the reason why it is not working is it have `<input type="checkbox" />` inside a span and click event is being added for span. I don't know the exact reason why checkbox is not let the event propogate but removing the checkbox works like a charm..

and yea one more thing `you haven't closed first span tag properly.`

working demo without checkbox **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ9ug/7/)**

use addClass() and removeClass() to acheive the effect you demo had.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add .dropdown_content li a,its working now..

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.dropdown').click( function(event){       
        event.stopPropagation();        
        $('.dropdown_content li a').toggle();      
    });   
});
```

Comment: when user click on anywhere other that dropdown. functionality stops working. I guess its not right.

Comment: it works fine until click on that area...but fails once click document,am working on it..